# Is there a ppa for nginx mainline with pagespeed?

Tags: ppa, nginx

I could only find a couple for the stable branch of nginx

Answer (score 0):

Yup EasyEngine Dev build has Nginx Mainline with Google Page speed Support

http://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home%3ArtCamp%3AEasyEngine-dev&package=nginx